# Sunburst in Python with Plotly Dash: Start at specific root after update

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Hi i am coding a Sunburst chart in python Plotly with Dash. [Sunburst v1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEpGV.png)
when i go deeper in the leafs [Sunburst v2 in first leaf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EknIf.png) and update the graph i get back to the top root[Sunburst v3 after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hexl.png).
can i start already in leaf? Or maybe simulate the clicks after the graph updates.
I already got the path, id with clickData. Thanks

Edit:[clickData Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckVGL.png) I can read the information when i click on Point in the Sunburstgraph. There has to be a way to start the sunburst again at this point right? Added some shortened code.

```
data_sunburst = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(namedict, orient='index',columns=['name','weight','Art', 'tp', 'impact', 'parent_key', 'child_list'])

app = dash.Dash(__name__) ##Starte Dash
styles = {
    'pre': {
        'border': 'thin lightgrey solid',
        'overflowX': 'scroll'
    }
}
app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H4(id="title",
            style={
                'textAlign': 'left'}
    ),
    html.Div([
        html.H5("Focus CM"),
        dcc.RadioItems(
            id='focus_cm',
            options=[
                    {'label': "True", 'value': "True"},
                    {'label': "False", 'value': "False"}],
            value="False"
        )]),
    html.Div([
        html.H5("Show T/B"), #color some areas
        dcc.RadioItems(
            id='show_tb',
            options=[
                {'label': "Show", 'value':"True"},
                {'label': "Dont", 'value':"False" }],
            value="False"
        )]),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Graph(id='sunburst'),

    html.Div([
        dcc.Markdown("""
    **Click Data**

    Click on points in the graph.
    """),
        html.Pre(id='click-data', style=styles['pre']),
    ], className='three columns'),
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output('click-data', 'children'),
    Output('title', 'children'),
    Input('sunburst', 'clickData'))

def display_click_data(clickData):
    click_path = "test"
    if clickData:
        click_path = clickData["points"][0]["id"]
        percentEntry = (clickData["points"][0]).get("percentEntry") ##Show all when returning to root
        parent = (clickData["points"][0]).get("parent")
        if percentEntry == 1 and parent == "test":
            click_path = "test"
    title = f"Selected from Sunburst Chart: {' '.join(click_path)}"
    return json.dumps(clickData, indent=2), title

@app.callback(
    Output('sunburst', 'figure'),
    Input('show_tb', 'value'))

def update_graph(show_tb_input):
    global focus_cm, show_tb, tp_dict
    
    if show_tb_input == "True":
        show_tb = True
    else:
        show_tb =False

    tp_dict = {"bsp": C_BSP, "wm": C_WM}  
    colors = set_colors_for_sunburst(namedict)   ##  set color when Show T/B input True;False
    fig = go.Figure(go.Sunburst(                 ## Build fig; Can i build already in Point from clickData?
        ids=data_sunburst.index,
        labels=data_sunburst.name,
        parents=data_sunburst.parent_key,
        values=data_sunburst.weight,
        branchvalues="total",  
        marker=dict(colors=colors),
        insidetextorientation="auto", 
    ))
    fig.update_layout(
        grid=dict(columns=2, rows=1),
        margin=dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0))
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: DId you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution:
Sunburst Object has paramenter level:
level – Sets the level from which this trace hierarchy is rendered. Set level to '' to start from the root node in the hierarchy. Must be an “id” if ids is filled in, otherwise plotly attempts to find a matching item in labels.